# How to read Assigned To column from SharePoint Workflow Tasks List using Powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, workflow-tasks-list

I am trying to fetch List details along with associated task columns to export into Excel using **PowerShell**. I am able to get all columns using following script except **Assigned To** column to show with which user the task is pending with from associated task list.

```
foreach ($item in $list.Items |  Where-Object { $_["Approval"] -eq "15"})
{
   foreach($workflow in $item.workflows)`
   {
      if($item.ID -eq $workflow.ItemId)
        {
         $wfName = $wf.Name
         $wfItem = $workflow.ItemName
         $wfPendingWith = $workflow.AssignedTo
         write-host "Title: $wfName  ListItem: $wfItem PendingWith:$wfPendingWith"
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please point out what am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I´m looking to do something similar and came across your question. I think you should drill down into the AssignedTo object, which is a user. Something like "$workflow.AssignedTo.UserName"